# Remove all levels from dates data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels, as.date

I have a dataset where one of the columns is dates but in character format. I used the following code to convert it to dates format and then take the month only:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- dmy(Austria$date)
Month <- month(dates, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```

The problem is that I am taking levels back for the months which I don't want to. I searched on how to remove the levels but everything I found was about removing levels that are unused (which is not my case).

I also, used the as,Date but I am still having the same problem:

```
dates_Austria <- as.Date(Austria$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

My final purpose is to make a plot which will have unemployment on the horizontal axis, income level on the vertical axis and then change the color of the plot according to the month, like that:

```
ggplot(data = my_data, aes(x = unemployment, y = income, colour = Month)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

But by using that code I am getting back different regression lines according to the month. I want one line for all the data and the the rest of the dots of the scatter plot to change colour according to the month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Does simply adding `group = -1` in the `aes()` function solve the problem?

Comment: @teunbrand Yes, thank you so much!!